# NLP stemming with JavaScript and PHP pages in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, nlp, stemming

I'm trying to figure out, how to implement and use [stemming](https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/stem) results with JavaScript and PHP pages in the browser.

By using `node index.js` in the VS Code terminal I got the output `word` using [natural](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural):

```
var natural = require("natural");
console.log(natural.PorterStemmer.stem("words"));
```

with [NLP.js](https://github.com/axa-group/nlp.js) librarie:

```
const { StemmerIt } = require("@nlpjs/lang-it");
const stemmer = new StemmerIt();
const input = ["ho", "visto", "uno", "sviluppatore"];
console.log(stemmer.stem(input));
```

they are [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) libraries, and I got an error in the Chrome browser console log using `require`:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
> at index.js:320:15

I'm not sure if there is some way to use libraries with the browser, like for example [Brain.js](https://brain.js.org/#/) providing [NPM and CND](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brain.js?activeTab=readme#NPM).

I did not try to use [Compromise.cool](https://github.com/spencermountain/compromise/) library yet, which can be used to run NLP on the browser, looking for a `stemming` method.

I've tried [Porters Stemming Algorithm Javascript](https://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/js.txt) but can't figure out, how to use it as a function. Seems like I'm doing it incorrectly:

```
var result = stemmer("words");
console.log(result);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: stemmer is not a function
> at index.js:346:14

Also, I've tried to follow [Natural Language Processing in the Browser](https://betterprogramming.pub/natural-language-processing-in-the-browser-8ca5fdf2488b) guide, separately installing each dependency listed in `package.json`:

```
"@nlpjs/core": "^4.14.0",
"@nlpjs/lang-en-min": "^4.14.0",
"@nlpjs/nlp": "^4.15.0",
"@nlpjs/request-rn": "^4.14.3",
"browserify": "^17.0.0",
"terser": "^5.3.8"
```

but `npm run build` throws the error:

> 10 error missing script: build

Any advice, guide, or example would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For browser side NLP & stemming look at the example of [stemming and lemmatization](https://observablehq.com/@winkjs/how-to-do-stemming-and-lemmatization?collection=@winkjs/winknlp-recipes). This Observable notebook and the associated collection contain details of making pure browser side NLP apps.